# Custom synchronization using java.util.concurrent with cats.effect

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, functional-programming, java.util.concurrent

I have a requirements of pretty custom non-trivial synchronization which can be implemented with a fair `ReentrantLock` and `Phaser`. It does not seem to be possible (without a non-trivial customization) to implement on `fs2` and `cats.effect`.

Since it's required to wrap all blocking operation into a `Blocker` here is the code:

```
private val l: ReentrantLock = new ReentrantLock(true)
private val c: Condition = l.newCondition
private val b: Blocker = //...

//F is declared on the class level
def lockedMutex(conditionPredicate: Int => Boolean): F[Unit] = blocker.blockOn {
  Sync[F].delay(l.lock()).bracket(_ => Sync[F].delay{
    while(!conditionPredicate(2)){
      c.await()
    }
  })(_ => Sync[F].delay(l.unlock()))
}
```

**QUESTION:**
Is it guaranteed that the code containing `c.await()` will be executed in the same `Thread` which acquires/releases the `ReentrantLock`?

This is a crucial part since if it's not `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown.

Comment: Maybe it may help if you can describe the synchronization problem you are trying to solve, maybe there is another way to achieve it on **cats-effect**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Given a set of threads I need to prioritize some of them allowing low priority ones to proceed only if there is no high priority threads have unfinished job. There is a lot of corners so some more advanced synchronizer then `Ref`/`Deffered` is required. In particular, `Phaser` is a great choice here.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez By running lots of experiments I found that probably such implementation is correct and works as expected.

Comment: When a low-priority thread picks a thread it has the right to finish its job before being taken over by another high-priority thread? Or if there is more high-priority jobs then it has to pause its progress in the middle?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez If there's higher priority threads then it has to finish the job and no low-priority threads can proceed until all high-priority finish their jobs.

Comment: That wasn't my question, my question was what happens if a low priority thread started to run and then a new high-priority job is submitted. Or there will never be new jobs?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez then low priority has to finish the currently running job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really do not need to worry about threads when using something like **cats-effect**, rather you can describe your problem on a higher level.

This should get the same behavior you want, it will be running high-priority jobs until there isn't more to then pick low-priority jobs. After finishing a low-priority job each fiber will first check if there are more high-priority jobs before trying to pick again a low-priority one:

```scala
import cats.effect.Async
import cats.effect.std.Queue
import cats.effect.syntax.all._
import cats.syntax.all._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object HighLowPriorityRunner {
  final case class Config[F[_]](
      highPriorityJobs: Queue[F, F[Unit]],
      lowPriorityJobs: Queue[F, F[Unit]],
      customEC: Option[ExecutionContext]
  )

  def apply[F[_]](config: Config[F])
                 (implicit F: Async[F]): F[Unit] = {
    val processOneJob =
      config.highPriorityJobs.tryTake.flatMap {
        case Some(hpJob) => hpJob
        case None => config.lowPriorityJobs.tryTake.flatMap {
          case Some(lpJob) => lpJob
          case None => F.unit
        }
      }

    val loop: F[Unit] = processOneJob.start.foreverM

    config.customEC.fold(ifEmpty = loop)(ec => loop.evalOn(ec))
  }
}
```

You can use the `customEC` to provide your own **ExecutionContext** to control the number of real threads that are running your fibers under the hood.

The code can be used like this:

```scala
import cats.effect.{Async, IO, IOApp, Resource}
import cats.effect.std.Queue
import cats.effect.syntax.all._
import cats.syntax.all._

import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main extends IOApp.Simple {
  override final val run: IO[Unit] =
    Resource.make(IO(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)))(ec => IO.blocking(ec.shutdown())).use { ec =>
      Program[IO](ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(ec))
    }
}

object Program {
  private def createJob[F[_]](id: Int)(implicit F: Async[F]): F[Unit] =
    F.delay(println(s"Starting job ${id} on thread ${Thread.currentThread.getName}")) *>
    F.delay(Thread.sleep(1.second.toMillis)) *> // Blocks the Fiber! - Only for testing, use F.sleep on real code.
    F.delay(println(s"Finished job ${id}!"))

  def apply[F[_]](customEC: ExecutionContext)(implicit F: Async[F]): F[Unit] = for {
    highPriorityJobs <- Queue.unbounded[F, F[Unit]]
    lowPriorityJobs <- Queue.unbounded[F, F[Unit]]
    runnerFiber <- HighLowPriorityRunner(HighLowPriorityRunner.Config(
      highPriorityJobs,
      lowPriorityJobs,
      Some(customEC)
    )).start
    _ <- List.range(0, 10).traverse_(id => highPriorityJobs.offer(createJob(id)))
    _ <- List.range(10, 15).traverse_(id => lowPriorityJobs.offer(createJob(id)))
    _ <- F.sleep(5.seconds)
    _ <- List.range(15, 20).traverse_(id => highPriorityJobs.offer(createJob(id)))
    _ <- runnerFiber.join.void
  } yield ()
}
```

Which should produce an output like this:

```
Starting job 0 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 1 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 0!
Finished job 1!
Starting job 2 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 3 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 2!
Finished job 3!
Starting job 4 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 5 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 4!
Finished job 5!
Starting job 6 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 7 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 6!
Finished job 7!
Starting job 8 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 9 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 8!
Finished job 9!
Starting job 10 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 11 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 10!
Finished job 11!
Starting job 15 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 16 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 15!
Finished job 16!
Starting job 17 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 18 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 17!
Finished job 18!
Starting job 19 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting job 12 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 19!
Starting job 13 on thread pool-1-thread-1
Finished job 12!
Starting job 14 on thread pool-1-thread-2
Finished job 13!
Finished job 14!
```

---

Thanks to Gavin Bisesi *(@Daenyth)* for refining my original idea into this!

---

*Full code available [here](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c8d7b47686052983f8e9818dd0cb5f7c)*.